# I can't install paho-mqtt

Tags: python, pip, paho

I tried to install paho-mqtt. I typed `pip install paho-mqtt` to install it and it was successful! But when I type `import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt` in my .py. The following error code is shown:

```
Import "paho.mqtt.client" could not be resolved.
```

What's wrong with it??? Please help me if you know how to fix it, thanks

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

try do this:

```
python -m pip install paho-mqtt
```

Comment: It said "Requirement already satisfied: paho-mqtt in c:\users\leung\onedrive\桌面\python's files\python\lib\site-packages (1.6.1)"

Comment: Are you maybe mixing Python versions? Or try to uninstall first, then try to install again